# Cabal-installed package not found with odd symbol errors

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've just updated `cabal-install` to 1.18 and tried to `cabal install` a package I'm working on locally called `language-torquescript`. When I try to run a simple file that imports my package, I get this bizarre error:

```
$ runhaskell examples/Basics.lhs

Basics.lhs: C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\cabal\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\languag
e-torquescript-0.1.0.0\libHSlanguage-torquescript-0.1.0.0.a: unknown symbol `_la
nguagezmtorquescriptzm0zi1zi0zi0_LanguageziTorqueScriptziParser_file1_closure'
Basics.lhs: Basics.lhs: unable to load package `language-torquescript-0.1.0.0'
```

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0 and working in Git Bash. In GHCi, I get another error:

```
Prelude> import Language.TorqueScript

Prelude Language.TorqueScript> :t file

Failed to load interface for `Language.TorqueScript.Parser'
There are files missing in the `language-torquescript-0.1.0.0' package,
try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

`ghc-pkg check` does nothing but give warnings about Haddock files that are missing. I just noticed that the path it's looking for (in `i386-windows-ghc=7.6.3`) is different to the path `ghc-pkg list` reports for the package:

```
$ ghc-pkg list language-torquescript

c:/Program Files (x86)/Haskell Platform/2013.2.0.0\lib\package.conf.d:

C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\ghc\i386-mingw32-7.6.3\package.conf.d:
    language-torquescript-0.1.0.0
```

How have I managed to get my system into this state, and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT: The other thing I had to do recently, in order to update `cabal-install`, was add `Users\Daniel\AppData...` to my path before the HP installation bin directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you've listed all your project's modules under `exposed-modules` or `other-modules` in your `.cabal`-file.

Comment: Oh... that may be it! I just checked out my code on another computer and realised one module is not exported for some reason. Must have made a `git` stuff-up somewhere. I'll test it tonight...

Comment: Yep, that did it, I was being dumb. Thanks!